# Sending Data From Java(GUI) to Python?

Tags: java, python, swing

I want to send the data that are getting from GUI component of java program to python program over serial(TxRx) link but I am new to serial programming. Do I need to use thread in this way of sending data (data from GUI component to serial line). I am also new to thread programming. Can anybody advice me? I really need that program. I have written my GUI program, if need I will sent it but I don't know how to upload the program code.
Thanks

Comment: I dont really understand why you are using serial communication.... ? is the gui on a different device than the python?

Comment: No, these two program are going to on the same device. The python program have to receive the data over serial link and the other program can be written in any language (I choose Java because of my experience).

Comment: do you actually need to code the other half or is this an excersize in pyserial?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [post](http://shazsterblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/arduino-google-voice-activated-servo.html). It shows Java and Python communicating over UDP Packets. And Java and Arduino communicating over Serial using RxTx Library for Java. You can use the code and modify Java and Python to communicate over Serial.

Comment: Thank for you reply. But I is difficult to understand. Really really thank you.